# FPDF -PHP -Call to undefined method

Tags: php, arrays, class, fpdf

I have been stuck on trying to print an array of data into a table in fpdf.
This is the tutorial I was following: 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Except it keeps saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method FPDF::FancyTable() in ...

I have seen many other questions like this but none of them are fixing mine.

I feel like this should be a really easy fix and I'm doing something dumb.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Colored table
function FancyTable($header, $data)
{
    // Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('','B');
    // Header
    $w = array(40, 35, 40, 45);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',true);
    $this->Ln();
    // Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    // Data
    $fill = false;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],'LR',0,'L',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[2],6,number_format($row[2]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[3],6,number_format($row[3]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
    }
    // Closing line
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
}
}

$csv = array();

$lines = file('../data/StaffData.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

$pdf = new FPDF();

// Column headings
$header = array('Country', 'Capital', 'Area (sq km)', 'Pop. ');
$data = $csv;
 $pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->FancyTable($header,$data);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

**UPDATE **
-Thanks for the help.
I did change the font and made no difference. I changed it from:

```
$this->SetFont('','B');
```

to

```
$this->SetFont('Arial','',14);
```

(In the fancy table function)

But it comes up with heaps of these errors:

> Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles...
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles...
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles...

I'm sorry, but I don't really know what to do.

However, I got some of the table to display by removing the lines with number_format. I.E I removed these two lines:

```
  $this->Cell($w[2],6,number_format($row[2]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
  $this->Cell($w[3],6,number_format($row[3]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
```

Any reason why? Its displaying the first two columns but not the rest of it.

Comment: The error is telling you that `$row[2]` and `$row[3]` are strings and not numbers so you can't use `number_format` unless you convert them from a string first.

Comment: Oh ok. I echoed them and the rows hold all the data in a string. How would I convert the strings into numbers? It seemed to work okay after removing the number_format and leaving the row though.
Thanks for your help hcoat. I will accept the answer anyway. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PDF class extends FPDF so you need to change

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

to

```
$pdf = new PDF();
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. That was one of the answer in a very similar question. But once I change that it comes up with "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Undefined font: B in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs..."

Comment: In the fpdf.php file it says:
class FPDF
and its Version: 1.81

Not sure if that means anything. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: FPDF can not use system fonts and only uses fonts in the FPDF font folder. It does come with some standard fonts but you must convert any other fonts that you would like to use and place them in the font folder.

Comment: Thanks hcoat, if you have time please see my edit/update.